# How does pandas know to only group and show these 3 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

[image: Image shows my dataset displayed by pandas]

I use groupby method to group data  by month. The ouput is exactly want I wanted.

[image: Image showing output from groupby method]

What I want to understand is, how does x display only 3 columns (Quantity Ordered, Price Each and Sales) and rejects the other columns shown in the dataset after I use the groupby method. Is it because the other data isn't numeric ? Is it because I used sum method along with groupby method ?

Comment: Yes, sum only took `numeric` data :)

Comment: You're exactly right, it's because the other data is non-numeric. If you want to apply specific aggregations to columns you can use agg instead of sum. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sum` is a numeric function, pandas would only apply it to the columns that are numeric.  This is described in the documentation as [Automatic exclusion of “nuisance” columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns).